# window.onload not working after page load chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, window.location

window.onload doesn't seem to run the specified function in the chrome console and I can't seem to find anyone with the solution.

Code:

```
function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
window.onload = preStart;
```

When ran the window.location successfully runs but "preStart" does not.
I realize that `window.onload` doesn't work after `window.location` but is there a solution to this? (Where the function runs after the page loads)

Since I am relatively new to JavaScript please explain any answers/solutions.

Any help with this would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You basicly are passing the preStart function to the window.onload method.

I see a bit misunderstanding in beginner javascript developers with the difference between preStart and preStart() functions.

in some cases like this:

```
SetTimeout(function(){

}, 2000)
```

you can pass directly a function to the SetTimeout, like you did above, so if your preStart has some logic that you want to execute after 2000 seconds you could:

```
SetTimeout(preStart,2000)
```

you can see that the function preStart was passed directly without '()' it doesn't need to be called since the SetTimeout expect the function.

in your case you want to execute the preStart on windows.load, so ou need the '()' to execute it.

So do something like this:

```
function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
window.onload = preStart();
```

Sorry if i i did a curve to explain the question, but i hope it helped.

Comment: The code at the end of your answer runs `preStart` before changing the page. I also tried using `setTimeout` with the following code: `function preStart() {console.log("Hello");}; window.location = 'https://www.google.com/'; setTimeout(preStart,2000);` Whilst the `setTimeout` starts successfully it function it is meant to start never starts after the page loads.